# AWS and GCP centrally managed airflows and Dataflow equivalent for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have two questions to ask:

1. So my company has 2 instances of airflow running, one on a GCP
   provisioned cluster and another on a AWS provisioned cluster. Since
   GCP has Composer, which helps you to manage airflow, is there a way
   to sort of integrate the airflow DAGs on the AWS cluster to be
   managed by GCP as well?
2. For Batch ETL/Streaming jobs(in python), GCP has Dataflow (Apache
       Beam) for that. What's the AWS equivalent of that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can't do it, till now you have to use AWS, provision it and manage by yourself. There are some options you can choose: EC2, ECS + Fargate, EKS
2. Dataflow is equivalent to Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR) or AWS Batch Dataflow. Moreover if you want to run current Apache Beam jobs, you can provision Apache Beam in EMR and everything should be the same